# Не получается адекватно заменить код php на js

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет! Помогите плиз заменить пару строк кода `php` в `wordpress` на аналогичное в `js`

```
$subdescription = $product->post->post_excerpt;
$subdescription = stristr($subdescription, 'Калорийность', true);
$subdescription = stristr($subdescription, 'Порция', true);
echo $subdescription;
```

Структура приблизительно такая, но может меняться. самое главное - исключить абзацы с подзаголовком `калорийность` и `порция`

```
<td>
<p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong><br>
Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em><br>
<strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em></p>
<hr>
<strong>Калорийность</strong><br>
<em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em><br>
<em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em><br>
<em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em><br>
<em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em><p></p>
</td>
```

Comment: Ваш запрос очень странно звучит. Как можно заменить этот код на код js, если он выполняется на сервере и отдает уже готовый результат клиенту. Код js из чего должен получать аналогичный результат?

Comment: @Visman т.е. js от сервера не может получить данные описания постов и с ними работать?

Comment: Если вы отправите данные клиенту и будете знать их структуру, то с помощью js вы сможете их обработать.

Comment: @Visman ок, добавил структуру

Comment: И все-таки, в чем ваш вопрос? На входе - приведенный текст, полученный с сервера, на выходе - вы хотите это в страницу вставить? Не понял вашего использование `strstr` - он у вас возвращает все до слова `порция` (с незакрытыми тагами), насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @Nickolay да, все правильно - задача в том, чтобы вернуть кусок текста до стоп слов. а чтобы закрыть все незакрытые теги где-то функцию специальную видел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дословный перевод: [определяем функцию stristr](http://phpjs.org/functions/stristr/) и затем:

```
var html = stristr(inputHtml, 'Калорийность', true);
html = stristr(html, 'Порция', true);
console.log(html);
$(куда-хотим-вставить).html(html);
```

(Единственное, я бы обрабатывал текст без `<td></td>` и вставлял итог в нужный эл-т `td`, тогда есть шансы, что html() все теги закроет адекватно.)

Не сказать, чтобы "адекватно", но если исходить из того, что у вас действительно такой адский HTML-markup, что-то более красивого придумать не получается.

Удобнее было бы, если бы у вас на уровне HTML были бы выделены стандартным образом эти "порции" и "ингредиенты", например обернуты в `<div class=...>`, тогда их можно было бы легко выделить и удалить из jQuery.

---

В текущем же виде за счет того, что jQuery не любит смешанные текст и элементы, красиво на уровне DOM этот кейс не решишь. Вот моя незаконченная попытка, если интересно:

```js
var $input = $("#test");
var $stopElts = $input.find('*').andSelf().contents().filter(function() {
  var m = this.nodeType == 3 &&
    this.nodeValue.match(/порция|калорийность/i) !== null;
  console.log(this.parentNode, this.nodeValue, m)
  return m;
});
$stopElts.parentsUntil($input).nextAll().add($stopElts).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="color: red">
  <p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong>
    <br>Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em>
    <br>
    <strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <strong>Калорийность</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Тут сделано предположение, что порция/ингредиенты расположены в элементе, который целиком удаляется. И не доделал удаление текстовых node (поэтому там двоеточие остается).